# What does "CRC presented high byte first" mean exactly?

Tags: c, crc, crc16

In the [Catalogue of parametrized CRC algorithms](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm), a couple of CRCs, namely CRC-16/XMODEM and CRC-16/GENIBUS have a point about "CRC presented high byte first." and I'm not entirely sure what that means but I'm wondering if it's relevant to the problem I'm facing.

For reference, I have a function computing the inverted (by inverted I mean one's complement. I'm not sure if this terminology is precise or not) crc-16/xmodem of a byte array but I always find myself having to flip the two bytes of the checksum (0xABCD to 0xCDAB) to match what I receive in the header packet. The CRC in the header packet is spanning two octets, with the LSB of the CRC in the first octet (lower address or `array[0]`) and the MSB of the CRC in the second octet (higher address or `array[1]`). I'm not entirely sure if it's relevant but I'm using a little-endian machine. The code is provided below.

One last thing is I also have to compute the CRC-32/CKSUM of the data blocks which are arranged in the same order (LSB of CRC `array[0]`) but I don't have to flip the order of the bytes or anything with the CRC32 checksum. I also provided this code below.

```c
uint16_t crc16(uint8_t *input, int len) {
    static unsigned int crc16_lut[] = {
        0x0000, 0x1021, 0x2042, 0x3063, 0x4084, 0x50A5, 0x60C6, 0x70E7,
        0x8108, 0x9129, 0xA14A, 0xB16B, 0xC18C, 0xD1AD, 0xE1CE, 0xF1EF,
        0x1231, 0x0210, 0x3273, 0x2252, 0x52B5, 0x4294, 0x72F7, 0x62D6,
        0x9339, 0x8318, 0xB37B, 0xA35A, 0xD3BD, 0xC39C, 0xF3FF, 0xE3DE,
        0x2462, 0x3443, 0x0420, 0x1401, 0x64E6, 0x74C7, 0x44A4, 0x5485,
        0xA56A, 0xB54B, 0x8528, 0x9509, 0xE5EE, 0xF5CF, 0xC5AC, 0xD58D,
        0x3653, 0x2672, 0x1611, 0x0630, 0x76D7, 0x66F6, 0x5695, 0x46B4,
        0xB75B, 0xA77A, 0x9719, 0x8738, 0xF7DF, 0xE7FE, 0xD79D, 0xC7BC,
        0x48C4, 0x58E5, 0x6886, 0x78A7, 0x0840, 0x1861, 0x2802, 0x3823,
        0xC9CC, 0xD9ED, 0xE98E, 0xF9AF, 0x8948, 0x9969, 0xA90A, 0xB92B,
        0x5AF5, 0x4AD4, 0x7AB7, 0x6A96, 0x1A71, 0x0A50, 0x3A33, 0x2A12,
        0xDBFD, 0xCBDC, 0xFBBF, 0xEB9E, 0x9B79, 0x8B58, 0xBB3B, 0xAB1A,
        0x6CA6, 0x7C87, 0x4CE4, 0x5CC5, 0x2C22, 0x3C03, 0x0C60, 0x1C41,
        0xEDAE, 0xFD8F, 0xCDEC, 0xDDCD, 0xAD2A, 0xBD0B, 0x8D68, 0x9D49,
        0x7E97, 0x6EB6, 0x5ED5, 0x4EF4, 0x3E13, 0x2E32, 0x1E51, 0x0E70,
        0xFF9F, 0xEFBE, 0xDFDD, 0xCFFC, 0xBF1B, 0xAF3A, 0x9F59, 0x8F78,
        0x9188, 0x81A9, 0xB1CA, 0xA1EB, 0xD10C, 0xC12D, 0xF14E, 0xE16F,
        0x1080, 0x00A1, 0x30C2, 0x20E3, 0x5004, 0x4025, 0x7046, 0x6067,
        0x83B9, 0x9398, 0xA3FB, 0xB3DA, 0xC33D, 0xD31C, 0xE37F, 0xF35E,
        0x02B1, 0x1290, 0x22F3, 0x32D2, 0x4235, 0x5214, 0x6277, 0x7256,
        0xB5EA, 0xA5CB, 0x95A8, 0x8589, 0xF56E, 0xE54F, 0xD52C, 0xC50D,
        0x34E2, 0x24C3, 0x14A0, 0x0481, 0x7466, 0x6447, 0x5424, 0x4405,
        0xA7DB, 0xB7FA, 0x8799, 0x97B8, 0xE75F, 0xF77E, 0xC71D, 0xD73C,
        0x26D3, 0x36F2, 0x0691, 0x16B0, 0x6657, 0x7676, 0x4615, 0x5634,
        0xD94C, 0xC96D, 0xF90E, 0xE92F, 0x99C8, 0x89E9, 0xB98A, 0xA9AB,
        0x5844, 0x4865, 0x7806, 0x6827, 0x18C0, 0x08E1, 0x3882, 0x28A3,
        0xCB7D, 0xDB5C, 0xEB3F, 0xFB1E, 0x8BF9, 0x9BD8, 0xABBB, 0xBB9A,
        0x4A75, 0x5A54, 0x6A37, 0x7A16, 0x0AF1, 0x1AD0, 0x2AB3, 0x3A92,
        0xFD2E, 0xED0F, 0xDD6C, 0xCD4D, 0xBDAA, 0xAD8B, 0x9DE8, 0x8DC9,
        0x7C26, 0x6C07, 0x5C64, 0x4C45, 0x3CA2, 0x2C83, 0x1CE0, 0x0CC1,
        0xEF1F, 0xFF3E, 0xCF5D, 0xDF7C, 0xAF9B, 0xBFBA, 0x8FD9, 0x9FF8,
        0x6E17, 0x7E36, 0x4E55, 0x5E74, 0x2E93, 0x3EB2, 0x0ED1, 0x1EF0
    };

    uint16_t crc = 0x0000;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < len; idx++)
        crc = (crc << 8) ^ crc16_lut[(crc >> 8) ^ (input[idx] & 0xff)];

    // The inverted remainder of division is the checksum
    return ~crc;
}
```

```c
uint32_t crc32(uint8_t *input, int len)
{
    static uint32_t crc32_lut[] = {
        0x00000000, 0x04c11db7, 0x09823b6e, 0x0d4326d9, 0x130476dc, 0x17c56b6b, 0x1a864db2, 0x1e475005,
        0x2608edb8, 0x22c9f00f, 0x2f8ad6d6, 0x2b4bcb61, 0x350c9b64, 0x31cd86d3, 0x3c8ea00a, 0x384fbdbd,
        0x4c11db70, 0x48d0c6c7, 0x4593e01e, 0x4152fda9, 0x5f15adac, 0x5bd4b01b, 0x569796c2, 0x52568b75,
        0x6a1936c8, 0x6ed82b7f, 0x639b0da6, 0x675a1011, 0x791d4014, 0x7ddc5da3, 0x709f7b7a, 0x745e66cd,
        0x9823b6e0, 0x9ce2ab57, 0x91a18d8e, 0x95609039, 0x8b27c03c, 0x8fe6dd8b, 0x82a5fb52, 0x8664e6e5,
        0xbe2b5b58, 0xbaea46ef, 0xb7a96036, 0xb3687d81, 0xad2f2d84, 0xa9ee3033, 0xa4ad16ea, 0xa06c0b5d,
        0xd4326d90, 0xd0f37027, 0xddb056fe, 0xd9714b49, 0xc7361b4c, 0xc3f706fb, 0xceb42022, 0xca753d95,
        0xf23a8028, 0xf6fb9d9f, 0xfbb8bb46, 0xff79a6f1, 0xe13ef6f4, 0xe5ffeb43, 0xe8bccd9a, 0xec7dd02d,
        0x34867077, 0x30476dc0, 0x3d044b19, 0x39c556ae, 0x278206ab, 0x23431b1c, 0x2e003dc5, 0x2ac12072,
        0x128e9dcf, 0x164f8078, 0x1b0ca6a1, 0x1fcdbb16, 0x018aeb13, 0x054bf6a4, 0x0808d07d, 0x0cc9cdca,
        0x7897ab07, 0x7c56b6b0, 0x71159069, 0x75d48dde, 0x6b93dddb, 0x6f52c06c, 0x6211e6b5, 0x66d0fb02,
        0x5e9f46bf, 0x5a5e5b08, 0x571d7dd1, 0x53dc6066, 0x4d9b3063, 0x495a2dd4, 0x44190b0d, 0x40d816ba,
        0xaca5c697, 0xa864db20, 0xa527fdf9, 0xa1e6e04e, 0xbfa1b04b, 0xbb60adfc, 0xb6238b25, 0xb2e29692,
        0x8aad2b2f, 0x8e6c3698, 0x832f1041, 0x87ee0df6, 0x99a95df3, 0x9d684044, 0x902b669d, 0x94ea7b2a,
        0xe0b41de7, 0xe4750050, 0xe9362689, 0xedf73b3e, 0xf3b06b3b, 0xf771768c, 0xfa325055, 0xfef34de2,
        0xc6bcf05f, 0xc27dede8, 0xcf3ecb31, 0xcbffd686, 0xd5b88683, 0xd1799b34, 0xdc3abded, 0xd8fba05a,
        0x690ce0ee, 0x6dcdfd59, 0x608edb80, 0x644fc637, 0x7a089632, 0x7ec98b85, 0x738aad5c, 0x774bb0eb,
        0x4f040d56, 0x4bc510e1, 0x46863638, 0x42472b8f, 0x5c007b8a, 0x58c1663d, 0x558240e4, 0x51435d53,
        0x251d3b9e, 0x21dc2629, 0x2c9f00f0, 0x285e1d47, 0x36194d42, 0x32d850f5, 0x3f9b762c, 0x3b5a6b9b,
        0x0315d626, 0x07d4cb91, 0x0a97ed48, 0x0e56f0ff, 0x1011a0fa, 0x14d0bd4d, 0x19939b94, 0x1d528623,
        0xf12f560e, 0xf5ee4bb9, 0xf8ad6d60, 0xfc6c70d7, 0xe22b20d2, 0xe6ea3d65, 0xeba91bbc, 0xef68060b,
        0xd727bbb6, 0xd3e6a601, 0xdea580d8, 0xda649d6f, 0xc423cd6a, 0xc0e2d0dd, 0xcda1f604, 0xc960ebb3,
        0xbd3e8d7e, 0xb9ff90c9, 0xb4bcb610, 0xb07daba7, 0xae3afba2, 0xaafbe615, 0xa7b8c0cc, 0xa379dd7b,
        0x9b3660c6, 0x9ff77d71, 0x92b45ba8, 0x9675461f, 0x8832161a, 0x8cf30bad, 0x81b02d74, 0x857130c3,
        0x5d8a9099, 0x594b8d2e, 0x5408abf7, 0x50c9b640, 0x4e8ee645, 0x4a4ffbf2, 0x470cdd2b, 0x43cdc09c,
        0x7b827d21, 0x7f436096, 0x7200464f, 0x76c15bf8, 0x68860bfd, 0x6c47164a, 0x61043093, 0x65c52d24,
        0x119b4be9, 0x155a565e, 0x18197087, 0x1cd86d30, 0x029f3d35, 0x065e2082, 0x0b1d065b, 0x0fdc1bec,
        0x3793a651, 0x3352bbe6, 0x3e119d3f, 0x3ad08088, 0x2497d08d, 0x2056cd3a, 0x2d15ebe3, 0x29d4f654,
        0xc5a92679, 0xc1683bce, 0xcc2b1d17, 0xc8ea00a0, 0xd6ad50a5, 0xd26c4d12, 0xdf2f6bcb, 0xdbee767c,
        0xe3a1cbc1, 0xe760d676, 0xea23f0af, 0xeee2ed18, 0xf0a5bd1d, 0xf464a0aa, 0xf9278673, 0xfde69bc4,
        0x89b8fd09, 0x8d79e0be, 0x803ac667, 0x84fbdbd0, 0x9abc8bd5, 0x9e7d9662, 0x933eb0bb, 0x97ffad0c,
        0xafb010b1, 0xab710d06, 0xa6322bdf, 0xa2f33668, 0xbcb4666d, 0xb8757bda, 0xb5365d03, 0xb1f740b4
    };

    uint32_t crc = 0;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < len; idx++)
        crc = (crc << 8) ^ crc32_lut[((crc >> 24) & 0xff) ^ (input[idx] & 0xff)];

    return ~crc;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I read it to mean [big endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: CRC theory is almost always assuming big endian, since most protocols work that way, with the MSB clocked in first and to be XOR:ed with the MSB of the polynomial. That's in fact how old times hardware CRC was implemented using XOR gates. Little endian is actually exotic, in terms of network endianess.

Comment: @Lundin Actually, no. The most common CRCs in use are reflected, processing the least significant bit of the message first. Such CRCs are then usually stored little-endian after the message to enable the check I mention in my answer.

Comment: @Lundin, I need to dissagree.  CRC protocols are bitwise protocols and represent polynomial division in Galois fields.  This process allows easy hardware implementation, but in practice the calculation in software, depends on how you calculate the table entries, and how are bits & bytes transferred on the wire.  Many protocols transfer LSb first (on a byte) and work ok, when the order of bytes is also LSB first, but it doesn't if this changes.  This means, on a bigendian machine transmitting bytes on a serial RS-232-C, you will need to swap bytes, so the bits are in order, once serialized.

Comment: @MarkAdler I'm speaking of [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/487359/6102) kind of implementation. For this to make sense, the MSB of the polynomial needs to be to the far left and matched with the MSB of the incoming data, clocked in from the far right.

Comment: @Lundin No, it does not need to be that way to "make sense". It is entirely up to the implementor as to whether the most significant bit or the least significant bit from the message arrives first on the left input of LFSR. It has been done both ways and works both ways. This is referred to in the linked CRC tables as not reflected and reflected respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code and the table, bit ordering is most significant bit first, and byte ordering for nearly all CRCs is most significant byte first. The issue is your processor is little endian, which is least significant byte first. If the memory contains 0xAB 0xCD in that order, a 16 bit little endian load into a register will result in the register having 0xCDAB.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the bytes of a non-reflected CRC (`refin=false refout=false`) would follow the message in big-endian order, with the high byte first. The reason is that then the same CRC of the message plus the CRC would be a particular constant if the message and CRC match. That may be why there are those notes. Those notes refer specifically to the protocols in which they originated.

However it is not required to verify a message with a CRC that way. You can instead just compute the CRC of the message and compare that to the CRC that came with the message. Then the CRC bytes can be in any order, and anywhere in the packet with the message. You just need to correctly assemble the bytes of the CRC into a word.

In your case, the CRC bytes are stored in little endian order in the packet. (And maybe *before* the message? I'm not sure if that's what you mean by `array[0]` and `array[1]`.) If that's how your protocol is defined, and that works, then fine. You have no problem.

It does not matter if your processor stores integers in little-endian or big-endian format, if you are accessing and building your packets as bytes. E.g. your `array[0]` and `array[1]` referencing the CRC bytes. (I am assuming that `array` is a `uint8_t *` or equivalent.) It would only matter if you were trying to store the CRC as a word in the array, e.g. `*(uint16_t *)array = crc;`, or read it from the array that way. Then the result would depend on the endianess of your machine. In that case your code would not be portable. It is recommended that you do it the way you're doing it, which is to explicitly put the high byte and the low byte of the CRC where they belong manually. Then the endianess of the machine it's running on doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the early days of networking, the issue of endianness had not been standardized yet, so when someone spoke of a data packet containing a value spanning more than one byte they had to specify the endianness of that value, otherwise some folks would attempt to interpret it as little endian, and other folks would attempt to interpret it as big endian, and chaos would ensue.

(Nowadays this is much less of a problem because we have largely come to the general agreement that "Network Order" shall mean "big endian", so the issue is largely settled. But in the old days it was not.)

So, "CRC presented high byte first" means "big endian", which means "Network Order".

Comment: This isn't necessarily about TCP/IP though, although most other kind of data protocols do use big endian as well. There are plenty of custom protocols for UART, CAN and so on, as well as industry and/or de facto standards for them. Some oddball scenarios with big endian on the data link layer but little endian on payload layers do exist as well.

Comment: Yes, it is not about TCP/IP, but anyone transferring data packets through any medium would be using "Network Order" if they are in their right mind.  Or at any rate "Network Order" tends to be the safe assumption if endianness is not explicitly mentioned.